# How do i prevent my app from uninstalling?

Tags: android

I am working on a security app. everything is fine, except there is a backdoor. the security can be easily removed by just uninstalling the app. is there a way i can protect my app from getting uninstalled by intruders? i'm sure this is possible as i have seen apps on google play store which cannot be uninstalled from settings.

Comment: The only apps that cannot be uninstalled (on a non rooted device) are system apps that are shipped with the OS. Apps you create can be uninstalled super easily and there is nothing you can do about it. And that's a good thing

Comment: @TimCastelijns you probably don't know much then. see Aks4125's answer, that is exactly what i'm talking about

Comment: That obviously doesn't work for 'regular' apps, if you are a IT admin or something and you have control over your user's phone's system, that is something you should have mentioned. There is no way you can prevent a user that is not associated with you from uninstalling a normal app that he downloaded via the play store. The app that Aks4125 mentioned, I just installed it and uninstalled with no problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer [Device Administrator](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html)

Once the application is registered as a Device Administrator, it can't be uninstalled unless its unregistered. This will prevent the app from being uninstalled.

For example [this application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.gtmedia.seekdroid) is using same functionality.

> Make sure if you install above application(SeekDroid) you must sign up then it will ask for device admin permission. :)

Comment: Note that you cannot read the terms you implicitly agree with when you sign up, because the page it refers to doesn't exist. So be warned