# How to create a system android app (which is can't be uninstalled)

Tags: android

How to create a system android app (which is can't be uninstalled)

System app development  is it possible or not ?

Comment: There is similar question. Please refer it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25446236/how-to-create-apps-in-android-which-cant-be-uninstalled-can-we-make-system-app

Comment: It is possible using device admin access. I've already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36306855/4647628)